# Select2 with angularjs and using ng-options not displaying correctly

Tags: angularjs-select2, ui-select2

Select Code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <select data-placeholder="Choose a user:" class="input-xxlarge" ui-select2="{allowClear: true}" data-ng-model="section.user_id" ng-options="user.id as user.name + ' (' + user.email + ')' for user in people" >
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Produced code: (removing ui-select2="{allowClear: true}")

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a user:" class="input-xxlarge ng-pristine ng-valid" data-ng-model="section.user_id" ng-options="user.id as user.name + ' (' + user.email + ')' for user in people">
    <option value="" class=""></option>
    <option value="0">Tiago (example@domain.com)</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Eduardo (example@domain.com)</option>
    <option value="2">Rodrigo (example@domain.com)</option>
</select>
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pAm7.png

Problem:
As you can see the produced code has the third option selected, and when i open the dropdown (image) is also selected, but while is closed (before being open for the first time) it doesnt show the selected option.

How it stays and how it should be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Gy5.png

So... if its selected (in the produced html) why it doesnt show as if it was selected?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ng-option attribute and try this:

```
<option ng-repeat="user in people" value="{{user.id}}">{{user.name}}</option>
```

Comment: I'm now using ng-repeat but still doesn't work... I notice that if I repeated the entire "select" tag it works... but just the second tag works as it should....